# How can I embed latest/newest song from soundcloud?

Tags: soundcloud

How can I embed a users latest song/ most recently posted onto my website via sound cloud's embed function?

I have tried changing the api.soundcloud.com/tracks to users and so on.

I have also tried to use the documentation soundcloud has provided without any luck.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: What language are you using ?